# Проблема с исключениями KeyboardInterrupt и IOError

Tags: python, python-3.x

В цикле `while` у меня идет парсинг сайтов черезе библиотеку `grab`.
Периодически вылетает ошибка от `grab`, которая имеет тип исключения `IOError`. Я её поймал. С этим проблем нет. Но мне требуется так же завершать цикл, нажатием <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>. Но в результате нажатия <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, вылетает ошибка `KeyboardInterrupt`, но цикл продолжается дальше...

```
while line:
  try:
    bla bla bla
  except IOError:
    line = line
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    break
  else:
    line = base_file.readline()
```

Answer (score 1):

Скрипт работает, просто запускаете его из консоли, а не из IDE. Я сначала запускал внутри `PyCharm`, и при <kbd>CTRL + С</kbd> цикл не прерывался, пока не попробовал его запустить из консоли.